# how to install api(youtube-api-search ) in spfx&React project created by yeoman-generator

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I created my project wth yeoman template generator;

`yo @microsoft/sharepoint`

command(react choosen as JS framework). than installed youtube search api

```
npm install youtube-api-search
```

so far everything seems ok.

[image]

But when I try to use api in project I encounter with "Cannot find module 'youtube-api-search'." here error messages in command line when I run "gulp serve";

I only added `import YTSearch from 'youtube-api-search';`  line to default code and I see these exceptions in commandline

[image]

here the lines if you cant see the image;

```
[11:02:03] Error - typescript - src\webparts\helloWorld\components\HelloWorld.tsx(6,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'youtube-api-search'.
[11:02:03] Error - 'typescript' sub task errored after 122 ms
 "TypeScript error(s) occurred."
```

I also checked youtube-api-search package exist under node_modules directory. so this error message makes no sense at all.. why this error occurs here and more important how can I able to use this api in yeoman generated project

Answer (score 0):

Any chance typescript maps modules to the ones defined in `package.json`?

Try `npm install --save youtube-api-search` so the module will be defined as a proper dependency.